# A Function to rank the sequence of events based on transactions in a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe, say:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+
|    day   |inout_amount|prev_balance|post_balance|row|
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+
|2016-10-29|      -17000|       17000|           0|  1|
|2016-10-30|      -17000|       17000|           0|  2|
|2016-10-30|        5600|           0|        5600|  3|
|2016-10-30|        5600|        5600|       11200|  4|
|2016-10-30|        5800|       11200|       17000|  5|
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+
```

the first row is correct for "2016-10-29" but the 4 rows beneath ("2016-10-30") is shuffled. here is the code for table above:

```
case class transaction(
 day: String, 
 inout_amount: Int, 
 prev_balance: Int,
 post_balance: Int
)

val snippet = Seq(
 transaction("2016-10-29", -17000, 17000, 0),
 transaction("2016-10-30", -17000, 17000, 0),
 transaction("2016-10-30", 5600, 0, 5600),
 transaction("2016-10-30", 5600, 5600, 11200),
 transaction("2016-10-30", 5800, 11200, 17000)
)

// below could be sparkContext if you working in zeppelin
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(snippet)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val window = Window.orderBy("day")

df.withColumn("row", row_number().over(window)).show
```

i now need to rank the rows for the "2016-10-30" based on the logic that the "prev_balance" is equal to the previous transaction's "post_balance". i.e. the desired dataframe should look like this:

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------+
|       day|inout_amount|prev_balance|post_balance|row|order-1|
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------+
|2016-10-29|      -17000|       17000|           0|  1|      0|
|2016-10-30|      -17000|       17000|           0|  2|      4|
|2016-10-30|        5600|           0|        5600|  3|      1|
|2016-10-30|        5600|        5600|       11200|  4|      2|
|2016-10-30|        5800|       11200|       17000|  5|      3|
+----------+------------+------------+------------+---+-------+
```

i am new to spark and guessing that i need to create a "udf" and then apply it with a "withColumn"... please help!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to groupBy date, sort your values according to your criterias and flatMap the result.  This can be done easily with RDDs.

Comment: Thanks, Michel i have been trying this but cannot get the desired results.